# How to read InnerException error in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the value from the key 'message'(Highlighted in the screenshot below)from an error exception. I tried the following, but it returns 'undefined':

```
(errors) => {
console.log(errors[0].extensions.response.body.errors[0].InnerException.Message)
}
```

[image]

Comment: `.message` -> `.Message`

Comment: my bad, corrected it, but still undefined.
even errors[0] returns undefined

Comment: Probably because you need `errors.errors[0]` - the object you have has `errors` as a key. It's not an array.

Comment: I wonder if a promise is being auto-fulfilled in the console during inspection: Try `console.log((await errors[0].extensions.response.json()).errors[0].InnerException.Message)`

Comment: following seem to work:

(error) => {
      const stringifiedData = JSON.stringify(error)
      const parsedData = JSON.parse(stringifiedData)
 console.log(parsedData.graphQLErrors[0].extensions.response.body.errors[0].InnerException.Message)
}


any idea why I have to parse it again, since it's already a json object?